# Identifying / digitising small surface features automatically in QGIS

Tags: qgis, dem, feature-extraction

I need to locate small features on a digital surface model (dsm) in qgis and get their coordinates.

I have a field surface with distributed molehills they show up in the dsm but is there a tool that will mark them as objects to digitise their locations?

[image]

I have QGIS + SAGA etc. but don’t know if there is a process to mark these without having to do it by hand (I have lots of fields to do!).

I was thinking about some way of setting an average surface height and then marking nodes above that height or some kind of feature processing plugin etc.

Comment: There are lots of threads discussing similar issues of programmatically finding local highs (or lows) in raster data. This one could be useful: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/259858/using-thermal-image-to-identify-hot-spots-automatically-and-converting-to-point