# How to convert boundaries in image to polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygonize

I have an [image from a cities districts and their boundaries](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Locator_maps_of_urban_units_of_Nuremberg#mediaviewer/File:N%C3%BCrnberg_Statistischer_Bezirke.svg) and I need them as polygons in QGIS.

I tried "Raster -> Conversion -> Polygonize (Raster to vector)" as described [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30274/identify-polygons-on-raster-image), but that vectorised every single pixel.

Comment: You would be better of downloading the Vector SVG file and converting that (will need to be georeferenced) http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11476/how-to-import-svg-into-gis svg> http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7e/N%C3%BCrnberg_Statistischer_Bezirke.svg

Answer (score 1):

Since the number of districts is quite low, you could just digitize them manually. That will probably be faster than anything else you try.

Otherwise, as Mapperz commented:

If you cannot get the data in a more appropriate format somewhere else, get the Vector SVG file and convert and georeference that. For more info on that issue see: [How to Import SVG into GIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11476/how-to-import-svg-into-gis)

http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7e/N%C3%BCrnberg_Statistischer_Bezirke.svg